# Restrict typescript type defines

Tags: typescript

I have a `Config` type defined like below:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;
type PrimitiveObject = {[key:string] : Primitive};

type Config = {
    baseUrl: string,
    timeout?: number,
    params?: PrimitiveObject,
    [key:string]: Primitive | PrimitiveObject | undefined
};

let conf1:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com"};

let conf2:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com", other: 0};

let conf3:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.ggogle.com", params: {id: 1}};

let conf4:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com", other: 0, other2: {hello: "world"} };
```

Now I want to constrain the attributes other than (`baseUrl`, `timeout`, `params`) to `Primitive`, not `Primitive | PrimitiveObject`. Just like `other2` in `conf4` should be an error.

I tried some methods but failed

```
type Config = {
    baseUrl: string,
    timeout?: number,
    params?: PrimitiveObject
} | {
    baseUrl: string
    [key:string]: Primitive
};

let conf1:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com"};

let conf2:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com", other: 0};

let conf3:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.ggogle.com", params: {id: 1}};

// other2 error, which is wanted
let conf4:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com", other: 0, other2: {hello: "world"} };

let conf5:Config = {other: 2}

// this is also valid, but params is not a PrimitiveObject, I want it throw error too
let conf6:Config = {baseUrl: "https://www.google.com", params: 1}
```

I'm new to TypeScript, any suggestions?

Comment: I am getting error for conf6. `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PrimitiveObject'`

Comment: do you want conf6 to throw error or not ?

Comment: @AmirSaleem I try in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play, conf6 doesn't throw an error, but I want it throw error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```ts
type Config = {
    baseUrl: string,
    timeout?: number,
    params?: PrimitiveObject
} | {
    baseUrl: string
    [key:string]: Primitive | undefined
    params?: never
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0L2xm)

Since `ts@4.4` with set [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) flag you can omit adding `| undefined` on the indexable field:

```ts
type Config = {
    baseUrl: string,
    timeout?: number,
    params?: PrimitiveObject
} | {
    baseUrl: string
    [key:string]: Primitive
    params?: never
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEDVgW)

Due to the bug in TS playground you'll have to manually toggle on `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` option in `TS Config` popup.